# JavaScript game error in controling the hit method

Tags: javascript, class

i got two players when player1 hits twice player2 player2's health decrease twice, but if player2 hits player1 twice player1's health decrease once

and the two  player belong to the same class
the game is made in mltifile but this is the classes files only

```
 class sprite {
    constructor({
        position,
        imageSrc ,
        scale = 1,
        framemax = 1 ,
        offset = {x:0,y:0}
        
    }) {
        this.position = position
        this.width = 50
        this.height = 150
        this.image = new Image()
        this.image.src = imageSrc
        this.scale = scale
        this.framemax = framemax
        this.framecurrent = 1
        this.framelapsed = 0
        this.framehold = 5
        this.offset = offset
 
    }
    draw(){
        C.drawImage(
            this.image ,
            this.framecurrent * (this.image.width / this.framemax) , 
            0,
            this.image.width / this.framemax ,
            this.image.height,

            this.position.x - this.offset.x,
            this.position.y - this.offset.y,
            (this.image.width / this.framemax) * this.scale,
            this.image.height * this.scale
            )

    }

    animateframe(){
        this.framelapsed++

        if (this.framelapsed % this.framehold ===0){

        if (this.framecurrent < this.framemax -1){
            this.framecurrent++
        }else {
          this.framecurrent = 0  
        }
        }
    }

    update(){
        this.draw()
        this.animateframe()
    }
}


class Fighter extends sprite{
    constructor({
        position,
        velocity ,
        color = 'red' ,
        imageSrc ,
        scale = 1,
        framemax = 1,
        offset = {x:0,y:0},
        sprites,
        attackbox ={offset:{},width:undefined,height:undefined}
    }) {
        super({
            position,
            imageSrc,
            scale,
            framemax ,
            offset 
        })
        
        this.velocity = velocity 
        this.width = 50
        this.height = 150
        this.lastkey
        this.attackbox = {
            position: {
                x:this.position.x , 
                y: this.position.y
            } ,
            offset : attackbox.offset,
            width: attackbox.width ,
            height : attackbox.height,
            
        }
        this.color = color
        this.isattacking
        this.health = 100
        this.framecurrent = 0
        this.framelapsed = 0
        this.framehold = 5
        this.sprites = sprites 
        this.dead = this.dead

        for (const Sprite in this.sprites) {
            sprites[Sprite].image = new Image()
            sprites[Sprite].image.src = sprites[Sprite].imageSrc
          }

        
    }

    update(){
        this.draw()
        if(!this.dead)
        this.animateframe()
    
        this.attackbox.position.x = this.position.x + this.attackbox.offset.x
        this.attackbox.position.y = this.position.y + this.attackbox.offset.y

        //C.fillRect(this.attackbox.position.x,this.attackbox.position.y, this.attackbox.width, this.attackbox.height)


        this.position.x += this.velocity.x
        this.position.y += this.velocity.y

        //gravity

        if(this.position.y + this.height +this.velocity.y >= canvas.height -97 ){
            this.velocity.y = 0
            this.position.y = 330
        }else this.velocity.y += gravity
        
       
    }

    attack2(){
      this.switchsprite('attack2')
        this.isattacking = true

    }
    
    attack1(){
      this.switchsprite('attack1')
        this.isattacking = true
    }

    takehit(){
      
      this.switchsprite('takehit')
      
      this.health -= 3

      if (this.health <= 0){
        this.switchsprite('death')
      }else this.switchsprite('takehit')
      
    }


    switchsprite(sprite) {
      if (this.image === this.sprites.death.image){
        if (this.framecurrent === this.sprites.death.framemax - 1) 
        this.dead = true
      return
    }

      if (
        this.image === this.sprites.attack1.image &&
        this.framecurrent < this.sprites.attack1.framemax - 1
        ) 
        return
      if (  this.image === this.sprites.attack2.image &&
        this.framecurrent < this.sprites.attack2.framemax - 1 )
         return

      if (
        this.image === this.sprites.takehit.image &&
        this.framecurrent < this.sprites.takehit.framemax - 1
        )
        return

      switch(sprite){
        case 'idle':
          if (this.image !== this.sprites.idle.image){
          this.image =this.sprites.idle.image
          this.framemax = this.sprites.idle.framemax
          this.framecurrent = 0
          }
          break;
        case 'run':
          if (this.image !== this.sprites.run.image){
          this.image =this.sprites.run.image
          this.framemax = this.sprites.run.framemax
          this.framecurrent = 0
          }
          break;
        case 'jump':
          if (this.image !== this.sprites.jump.image){
          this.image = this.sprites.jump.image
          this.framemax = this.sprites.jump.framemax
          this.framecurrent = 0
          }
          break;  
          case 'fall':
            if (this.image !== this.sprites.fall.image){
            this.image = this.sprites.fall.image
            this.framemax = this.sprites.fall.framemax
            this.framecurrent = 0
            }
            break;
            case 'attack2':
              if (this.image !== this.sprites.attack2.image){
              this.image = this.sprites.attack2.image
              this.framemax = this.sprites.attack2.framemax
              this.framecurrent = 0
              }
              break;
            case 'attack1':
                if (this.image !== this.sprites.attack1.image){
                this.image = this.sprites.attack1.image
                this.framemax = this.sprites.attack1.framemax
                this.framecurrent = 0
                }
                break;
            case 'takehit':
                  if (this.image !== this.sprites.takehit.image){
                  this.image = this.sprites.takehit.image
                  this.framemax = this.sprites.takehit.framemax
                  this.framecurrent = 0
                  }
                  break; 
            case 'death':
              if (this.image !== this.sprites.death.image){
              this.image = this.sprites.death.image
              this.framemax = this.sprites.death.framemax
              this.framecurrent = 0
            }
            break;      
 
      }
    }
  }
```

the two player hit once and the pause for .5s and then be able to hit again